# Need help to shorten this jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code that works well [here](https://jsfiddle.net/moinchoudhari/xb5foo12/)

Need help in doing something like this:

```
$('.date-container input').click(function() {
    var j;
    for (j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {

        $('.day' + (j + 1) + '-times').hide('slow');

        $(this).$('.day' + (j + 1) + '-times').show('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work that well - it still shows me 'day 2' items when i uncheck that box

Comment: `j !== i`.........???

Comment: Try: `[...Array(4)].forEach((x,i)=>{ /*code inside your for-loop */ });`

Comment: Also, `$(this).$` is just wrong, you are able to use `$(this).find` instead, but I doubt there will be something inside an `input`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have not target checked attr at this time, it's on click only.

Comment: thanks everyone for your time, will try to be more specific next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a shorter version of your fiddle JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // When document is ready, we bind the click event on every 'input' in the '.date-container' div 
  $('.date-container input').click(function(){
    // When a click event is triggered on one of those 'input', we hide
    // all the 'div' that are in the '#checkboxradio' element 
    $('#checkboxradio > div').hide('slow');
    // Using the 'id' attribute of the input that triggered the clicked
    // event (e.g. "day1"), we build a jQuery selector that'll be used
    // to select the proper checkboxes time container
    // (e.g. "." + "day1" + "-times" = ".day1-times")
    // Then we stop all animations on that element (prevent hiding if 
    // it's the element we actually want to display)
    // and trigger a show animation on that same element
    $('.' + $(this).prop('id') + '-times').stop().show('slow');
  });
});
```

You probably want to switch to radios from checkboxes

Comment: that works perfectly well for my case. I need multiple dates selected at a time, therefore had used checkboxes over radio. Thank you and everyone else for your time.

Comment: I added comments to my answer :). Cheers !